# PL/SQL anonymous block completed" with no result displayed

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

When I executed the code below i got the message "anonymous block completed" without any results back. Can anyone help me out?

```
BEGIN
 FOR r IN
 (SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL
 (object_type => 'VIEW', name => view_name, schema => USER)
 AS view_text
 FROM USER_VIEWS)
 LOOP
 IF INSTR (r.view_text, 'Project') > 0 THEN
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (r.view_text);
 END IF;
 END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Before running this piece of code, you have to enable output. In SQL*Plus and SQL Developer, it is done by running

```
set serveroutput on
```

PL/SQL Developer must have something similar, either by explicitly running that statement (if it is supported), or by clicking somewhere in the output window so that `DBMS_OUTPUT` has something to display the result to.

Comment: I just did that and had a syntax error on the word "ON". Do i need to add anything else?

Comment: That syntax error is color coded in Pink and as i said, it is on the word ON of the suggested code.

Comment: In PL/SQL Developer, you enable dbms_output via a checkbox in the 'Output' tab. However, it doesn’t report *'anonymous block completed'* (the message is *'Executed in 0.001 seconds'*) so not sure how you’re getting that.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found this (in case someone needed):

SQL Developer seems to only output the DBMS_OUTPUT text when you have explicitly turned on the DBMS_OUTPUT window pane.

Go to (Menu) VIEW -> Dbms_output to invoke the pane.

Click on the Green Plus sign to enable output for your connection and then run the code.

Comment: Wait a minute. You tagged the question with "PL/SQL Developer" tag, not "SQL Developer". Former is owned by Allround  Automations, latter by Oracle. Which one do you really use?

Comment: @cesaviso So the question is actually how to enable dbms_output in SQL Developer?